# Removing target directory makes code uncompilable in playframework when using compile time dependency injection

Tags: playframework-2.6

My code was working fine. I deleted the `target` directory and the code stopped compiling. I suppose it is because `play` creates certain files automatically (eg `routes`) which it can't find any longer. How could I make the code compile again.

The errors are

```
Error:(18, 8) not found: object router
import router.Routes
Error:(415, 25) not found: type Routes
  lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController,userWSRoutes, questionsWSRoutes, answersWSRoutes,assets)
C:\...\code_related\code\frontend\web\app\controllers\HomeController.scala
Error:(74, 27) object index is not a member of package views.html
            Ok(views.html.index(message, messagesApi("app.title")(langs.availables(0)),userCookieOption.get.value,resetPasswordToken.get.value))
Error:(76, 27) object index is not a member of package views.html
            Ok(views.html.index(message, messagesApi("app.title")(langs.availables(0)),"",""))
```

Referring to the documentation, I suppose Play generated `router.Routes` file and it can't find it now as I deleted the `target` directory. I thought that recompiling the code would regenerate it but probably it doesn't. - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection

I am using Intellij IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved if I use `build project` option instead of `build` in `IntelliJ` IDE's `edit configuration`. It seems `build project` rebuilds everything while `build` just does incremental build